# Passing arguments to function inside sapply

Tags: r, sapply

Lets say that we have a list with numbers and we apply a function,
for example the mean function, to each element of the list:

```
l <- list(a = 1:10, b = 11:20)
l.mean <- sapply(l, mean)
l.mean # it works
```

But what if the list consists of strings and we want to paste them:

```
ll <- list(a=c("1", "2"), b=c("3", "4"))
ll.paste <- sapply(ll, as.call(list(paste, ll, sep = ", ")))
ll.paste # it does not work
```

The output I expect should be something like that:

```
# 1, 2
# 3, 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need the `collapse` argument of `paste`.

```
 unname(sapply(ll, paste, collapse=', '))
```

A wrapper function for `paste(., collapse=', ')` is `toString`

```
 unname(sapply(ll, toString))
```

Comment: You are totally right. And I didn't know unname function. Tnx a lot